# How can I exactly find out what outgoing interface is using?

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus

I need to identify what outgoing interface is using for some destination address.
*show ip route* tells me several BGP routes to this destination, how can I exactly find out what switch's interface will be used? ECMP plays some role in this case, if I'm not mistaken.

```
pd01-ilf-005# sh ip route a.b.c.d/32
IP Route Table for VRF "default"
'*' denotes best ucast next-hop
'**' denotes best mcast next-hop
'[x/y]' denotes [preference/metric]
'%<string>' in via output denotes VRF <string>

a.b.c.d/32, ubest/mbest: 2/0
    *via 10.0.1.4, [20/0], 19w5d, bgp-4200020005, external, tag 4200000002
    *via 10.0.1.132, [20/0], 19w5d, bgp-4200020005, external, tag 4200000002
pd01-ilf-005# sh forw 1.2.3.4

slot  1
=======


IPv4 routes for table default/base

------------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------
Prefix            | Next-hop                                | Interface            | Labels          | Partial Install
------------------+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+-----------------+-----------------
*a.b.c.d/32     10.0.1.4                                  Ethernet1/49
                     10.0.1.132                                Ethernet1/50

BGP routing table entry for a.b.c.d/32, version 485974
Paths: (2 available, best #2)
Flags: (0x8008001a) (high32 00000000) on xmit-list, is in urib, is best urib route, is in HW
Multipath: eBGP

  Path type: external, path is valid, not best reason: newer EBGP path, multipath, no labeled nexthop, in rib
  AS-Path: 4200000002 4200020006 , path sourced external to AS
    10.0.1.4 (metric 0) from 10.0.1.4 (10.0.27.125)
      Origin incomplete, MED not set, localpref 100, weight 0

  Advertised path-id 1
  Path type: external, path is valid, is best path, no labeled nexthop, in rib
  AS-Path: 4200000002 4200020006 , path sourced external to AS
    10.0.1.132 (metric 0) from 10.0.1.132 (10.0.27.126)
      Origin incomplete, MED not set, localpref 100, weight 0

  Path-id 1 advertised to peers:
    10.0.98.173        10.0.98.189
```

Comment: 169.254.0.0/16 is *not routable* (or shouldn't be). Is your question especially about routing these addresses or is it just a bad example?

Comment: @Zac67, in our case this net is routable, but it's not matter. I need find out an answer in general, common case, for every cases, I mean.

Comment: Then you should consider editing your question accordingly. As it is you might not get any reasonable answers. 169.254.0.0/16 addresses are link-local only and can exist any multiple interfaces. For routing it is a particularly bad example since that "destination subnet" doesn't exist coherently.

Comment: @Zac67, thanks, I've edited it. Hope it's helps me to find out an answer :-)

Comment: "_in our case this net is routable_" No, by definition addresses in the link-local range of `169.254.0.0/16` cannot be routed, and routers are _required_ to not route such traffic. _[RFC 3927](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3927.html#section-2.7):_ "_An IPv4 packet whose source and/or destination address is in the 169.254/16 prefix MUST NOT be sent to any router for forwarding, and any network device receiving such a packet MUST NOT forward it, regardless of the TTL in the IPv4 header._" IANA also bans routing of link-local addresses.

Comment: @RonMaupin maybe it is related to routing between BGP AS? In particular AS we can route whatever we want.
spine# sh ip route | sec 169.254
169.254.32.0/26, ubest/mbest: 1/0
    *via 10.0.1.5, [20/0], 19w5d, bgp-4200000002, external, tag 4200020005
169.254.34.0/24, ubest/mbest: 1/0
...
But is not my deсision to use these addresses. I don't know why my co-workers configured DC in this way. Maybe it has some sense. Who knows.   169.254.x.x/31 are used as interconnect between leaf and spine switches.

Comment: If you are routing link-local packets, then you are violating the standards, and you should expect problems. The standards are there for a reason. Unfortunately, there are cases where device OSes let you violate the standards, e.g. Linux, but that does not mean it is OK or advised to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, ECMP paths are *equal*. A given packet takes one of the possible routes, seemingly at random. Routers choose one of the paths based on interface load, queue depth, plain round robin, ...

There may be policies in place that prefer one route over the others (based on source address, L4 protocol, L4 port number, session, ...), but there's no standard for this (that I know of). Often, "ECMP" is actually much more PBR in practice.

Comment: If it's using a "per session" method, there should be a route cache showing which path was selected. If it's hash based, you'll need to find the hash function (not always documented.) While routing doesn't really care about "shotgunning" of packets, but it often leads to out-of-order delivery.